# Monitor power blinking but no display

Tags: display

I have a Samsung SyncMaster 943NW that I found in my storage room and it worked perfectly fine for a few months until now, when I turn on the monitor it has no display and the power light is blinking.

The LED usually don't blink and when there's nothing connected to the monitor there will be something popping up but there's nothing there.

I tried unplugging the power and signal cable and put it back on but it still has the same problem.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you are not confortable to fix the monitor yourself, there is nothing you can do. This is due to most probably bad capacitors. ([1](https://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=37549),[2](http://www.fixya.com/support/t7142738-samsung_943nw_monitor_led))

Comment: The only way to fix it is to bring it to a repair-man, and the repair-cost might be more than a new monitor. Is it worth it for a 10-year old monitor? If you have a friendly technician that will take a look without charging anything, then ask him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your monitor seems to be failing and it won't get better.

If you are not comfortable to fix the monitor yourself (fine soldering), there is nothing you can do since it's probably due to [bad capacitors](https://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=37549), ([2](http://www.fixya.com/support/t7142738-samsung_943nw_monitor_led)) on the board which can be fixed but considering the age of the monitor and the money it would take to repair it, it's not worth the effort.